# Javascript: Change specific part of the hash

Tags: javascript, regex, url, hash

So for example I have:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php#/parameter1=one/parameter2=two/
```

Now how should I update only the `parameter1`'s value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
location.href.replace(/#\/parameter1=\w*/, "#/parameter1="+NEW_VALUE)
```

Comment: replace \w with [^&]* and you might actually have something there.

Comment: Brilliant `replace` is what I need here :D lol I don't know how could I miss it...

Comment: heh, i didn't mean [^&]*, I meant [^/]* so that if someone did one+two in one parameter it would be allowed.

Comment: @Mike in this way you are allowing all other characters like #&? which are not ok and should be escaped.

Comment: yes and how would you escape them? Typically with a % which is what you need to allow. I think the safest replacement for \w* is probably [^/&#]*, which allows for using /, or the standard # and & separators.